# Send to class char array defined in header

Tags: c++, class, header-files, arrays

The issue that I am having is that I am trying to build a DLL. And I am using char instead of strings to store information.

I have defined the following in the header file:

```
class Test{
public:
    int qLenght;
    char firstName[];
    char surName[];
};
```

I am having problems inputting codes from the main program using the following:

```
int main()
{

        Test theTest;
        theTest.firstName[0] = {"Mike Smith","Jonny Vegas","Jimmy Woo"};

}
```

I have included the header code at the top of my main project.

It won't let me add to the char array. This may seem like a stupid question but I am struggling and hopefully someone can shed some light as to where I am going wrong. Am I missing a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class needs to know how much memory to allocate when you instantiate the class (which is not the same time as you assign the values).

```
class Test
{
public:
    char firstName[2][100];
};

int main()
{
    Test theTest;
    strcpy(theTest.firstName[0], "Mike Smith");
    strcpy(theTest.firstName[1], "Jonny Vegas");
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can allocate memory for the strings dynamically at the time of assignment, but then you need to remember to free it again:

```
class Test{
public:
    char *firstName[2];
};

int main()
{
    Test theTest;
    theTest.firstName[0] = strdup("Mike Smith");
    theTest.firstName[1] = strdup("Jonny Vegas");

    // do stuff

    free(theTest.firstName[0]);
    free(theTest.firstName[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vandhunden. Well explained and make sense. Thank you.

Comment: Hi  Vandhunden, Sorry will not let me upvote as I am new to this and don't have enough reputation to upvote. Sorry!